# Class Referencing

Tags: python, oop

I have two files: `class1.py` and `class2.py`

In the file `class2.py` I have a class that requires me to inherit a class in `class1.py`:

In file `class2.py` I have the following import function

```
import class1 as class1   #is the right way to do it?
```

My question is do I need to define the class like this:

```
class temp(class1):
    ...
```

or like this:

```
class temp(class1.class1)
    ...
```

Comment: `import class1 as class1` -> `import class1` :)

Comment: Thanks! The reason I am asking is in class `temp` I will be implementing methods that will require objects in `class1.py`, so will I thought giving it a namespace will allow me to reference properly.

Comment: could you please change the title, because super means something else and it might get confuse who search for super in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the second form.

```
class temp(class1.class1):
   ...
```

With how you've import `class1`, in your `class2` module, `class1` is a *reference* to the `class1` *module* which holds the `class1` *class*.

The alternative is to only import the `class1` *class* from the `class1` *module*:

```
from class1 import class1

class temp(class1):
    ...
```

---

In general, to avoid these problems, you're best bet is to follow PEP 8 naming conventions -- Classes should be written as `UppCaseWords`, modules should use `names_with_underscores`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't give the file the same name of a class inside it, or Python won't know which one you want to refer to. You can call the file `class1_file.py`. Then when importing:

```
import class1_file as c1
```

and then use `class1` as:

```
class temp(c1.class1):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to import a class which is itself lying in class1.py you need to use the second method - but as far as your code says there is a class called class1 in class1.py- if this is correct then go for second method. 'as' in import just makes it easy to use lengthy class names as shorter ones or to differentiate between any similar imported class names. So that wouldn't make much difference.